# How to wrap a LinkButton in li tag from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to generate a list of links from my code-behind page and wrap each link in a `<li>` tag

In the mark up page I have:

```
<ul>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ListOfLinks" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ul>
```

In the code behinde page on Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList linkList = new ArrayList();
    linkList.Add("LinkText 1");
    linkList.Add("LinkText 2");
    linkList.Add("LinkText 3");

    foreach (string linkItem in linkList)
    {
        LinkButton LButton = new LinkButton();

        LButton.ID = linkItem.ToString() + "Link";
        LButton.Text = linkItem.ToString();
        LButton.Click += new EventHandler(LinkPost_OnClick);

        ListOfLinks.Controls.Add(LButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include two `Literal` controls in the loop:

```
foreach (string linkItem in linkList)
{
    Literal l1 = new Literal();
    l1.Text = "<li>";
    ListOfLinks.Controls.Add(l1);

    //add linkbutton

    Literal l2 = new Literal();
    l2.Text = "</li>";
    ListOfLinks.Controls.Add(l2);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works fine. I tried to create l1 and l2 out of the foreach and only add them in the foreach loop, but the result was `<li>` tags were added only to the last item. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Necvetanov, sorry, I don't know what you mean? Both `l1` and `l2` are added in every loop.

Comment: Yes your solution works as expected. But I tried to create the literals l1 and l2 out of the foreach loop and the result was that only the last item got wrapped in `<li>` tag. And I don't understand why do I have to create new literals for every item instead of reusing them.

Comment: you are not re-using them, just overwriting the same literal with the same text over and over.